# Detecting pixel colour from "dynamic" image scraped online

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to python and opencv. I'm trying to learn both at the same time to make things more interesting.

I was trying to detect if certain pixels in an image online are of a certain colour (green). The image online would always be updated so the pixels in question wouldn't always have the same colour, hence the urllib.
I used a loop to go through all the specific pixels I wanted to check.

```
import urllib.request
import cv2
# import numpy as np


def download_status(url):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "boxes.jpg")


# List with representative pixels of each box, total 8 boxes
box_cords = [[62, 42], [144, 42], [234, 42], [312, 42], [62, 133], [144, 133], [234, 133], [312, 133]]

# List describind box status/colour; 0-gray 1-green
box_status = [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]


download_status("https://image.ibb.co/chtUW6/boxes.png")

box_scheme = cv2.imread("boxes.jpg")
for box in box_cords:
    box_colour = box_scheme[box]
    #  print(box_colour)
    if box_colour == "[51 204 52]":
        box_status[box] = 1

#  print(box_status)
```

Unfortunatly I'm getting a warning: "FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison"

Also while debugging by printing variables that express colour, I always get the same values (255 255 255). And I'm not sure If I'm comparing the colours in the loop correctly in terms of syntax, which is quite probably the reason for the warning.

I treid searching for the warning and of ways to do what I'm trying to achieve but failed to find anything useful..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does pyimagesearch help: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/04/opencv-python-color-detection/

Comment: (255, 255, 255) in RGB colour space is white. Which line does the error refer to?

Comment: The [255 255 255... 255 255 255] appears when I try to print box_colour.
Like this: [255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 ...... 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255]

Comment: Changed the if statement to if box_colour == (51, 204, 52): so the warning disappeared.

So now I'm just trying to figure a way to get the correct RGB colour from the pixels specified in the list.

Comment: png vs jpeg? Your url suggests png, but other references are to jpeg. They’re different file formats.

Comment: Oh I thought the filetype wouldn´t influence at all. Once the image (.png) is scraped, it's renamed (.jpeg) and used.

But i already changed everything to .png and the problem still persists..

Thanks for all the help so far though @Pam

Comment: Does it open ok as a jpeg (that is, can you open the file by double clicking it or whatever on your operating system)? Png is a lossless image format, jpeg is compresses. Just renaming it without changing the file inside might cause read problems.